# Issues with drop down menu only on IE9

Tags: html, css

I've got a perfectly working css dropdown/popover menu which only has issues in IE9. Issue with IE9 is that when I hover it fast enough menu works and I have to be super precise.

Here is my css :

```
#meta_menu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index:5000;
}

#meta_menu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#meta_menu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) #FAFAFA;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#meta_menu > ul ul > li { 
position: relative;
margin:0px;
z-index: 1;
}

#meta_menu ul ul a{
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
    font-family: FuturaTT,Georgia,Palatino,Times New Roman,serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light','Helvetica Neue Light','Helvetica Neue',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#meta_menu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}

#meta_menu ul ul a{
background:none;
}

#meta_menu ul ul a:hover{
   color:#888 !Important;
}
```

My HTML :

```
<div id="meta_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">NOTIFICATIONS <span class="notifications badge">0</span></a></li>
                    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">RECENT PAGES</a>
                         <ul>
                             <li><a href='#'>Page 1</a></li>
                             <li><a href='#'>Page 2</a></li>
                             <li><a href='#'>Page 3</a></li>
                             <li><a href='#'>Page 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="meta_last"><a href="#" class="tips sign_out">SIGN OUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

How does one troubleshoot these kind of issues with IE? Do you have general guidelines you stick with IE? I've tried tried putting width 100 % to the li element/tried setting display block/zoom 1 it worked for me in some cases, not not though. Can anyone recommend where would I get started?

Here is a fiddle code which replicates the issue :

http://jsfiddle.net/phKsk/2/

Comment: I replicated your code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/phKsk/ and it worked fine on my IE9. Does it work for you?

Comment: @HenriqueFeijo I've updated a fiddle it seems to have issues when its below not on side. Try for yourself when you hover on the RECENT PAGES and then go right outside Page x it dissapears .. here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/phKsk/2/ thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that IE9 does not support css transitions.

On all other browsers, when you mouse over RECENT PAGES, you will have .3 seconds (as defined in your css) to reach the submenu before it disappears, and once reached it won't disappear. Since IE9 does not support transform, you basically have 0 seconds until you mouse over the submenu.

So the only way to fix this in IE9, is to have the submenu touching the link RECENT PAGES.

If you add in #meta_menu > ul > li > ul the following

> ```
> margin-top: -30px;
> padding-top: 30px;
> ```

You will see what I am talking about. Of course this code will mess with the design of the submenu, but you can accomplish the same by using a container around the UL having the same effect.